App crashing while running with live edit
I have a problem. Don't know why but android studio live edit simply crashes the app. And there is no reason. I didn't change something in gradle or manifest, but this bug appears.
Logcat:
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 12176 (e.waterreminder), pid 12176 (e.waterreminder)
Cmdline: com.example.waterreminder
pid: 12176, tid: 12176, name: e.waterreminder  >>> com.example.waterreminder <<<
NOTE: Function names and BuildId information is missing for some frames due
NOTE: to unreadable libraries. For unwinds of apps, only shared libraries
NOTE: found under the lib/ directory are readable.
NOTE: On this device, run setenforce 0 to make the libraries readable.
NOTE: Unreadable libraries:
NOTE:   /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#01 pc 000000000007b4ec  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#02 pc 00000000000b46b3  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#03 pc 0000000000072076  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#04 pc 00000000000b626b  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#05 pc 00000000000a7d2f  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#06 pc 0000000000091514  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#07 pc 0000000000072839  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#08 pc 00000000000611e4  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#54 pc 00000000000b75f4  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#55 pc 0000000000057ebe  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#56 pc 00000000000581f3  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#57 pc 0000000000061cf9  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#58 pc 000000000006198e  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#59 pc 0000000000061811  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#60 pc 0000000000066d1d  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#61 pc 0000000000065fd3  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#62 pc 000000000005721c  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so
#63 pc 00000000000578f4  /data/data/com.example.waterreminder/code_cache/startup_agents/7cce5689-agent.so

I tired to turn on Always install with package manager in app settings, but it didn't help.
If you need here is build gradle code:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
    //Kapt
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    //Hilt
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.waterreminder"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.waterreminder"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    //DataStore impl
    implementation(libs.androidx.datastore.preferences)
    //Room db impl
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.ktx)
    implementation(libs.firebase.storage.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3.android)
    //noinspection KaptUsageInsteadOfKsp
    kapt(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    //Hilt impl
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    kapt(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
    //Coil impl
    implementation(libs.coil.compose)
    //Nav impl
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.navigation.animation)
    //System bars color impl
    implementation(libs.accompanist.systemuicontroller)

    //Basic impl
    implementation(libs.androidx.animation.graphics.android)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.androidx.graphics.shapes.android)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom.v20240401))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom.v20240401))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
}


did you found a solution?

Upgrade your jetpack compose bom version
You are using v20240401, replace with latest version v20240600
implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom.v20240600))
androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom.v20240600))

Clean and rebuild the project and try again. I hope it will solve the issue

this didn't work for me

@karique yes. you may have other issues. check your error logs and find out the cause of the issue. You can ask separate question with your error.

Here are possible ways you can try out to resolve the issue:

Try invalidating caches.
Clean and Rebuild the project from Build menu.
Try running app on a different emulator or physical device.
Disable and re-enable Live Edit from Settings.
Make sure that the Active Build Variant is set to debug. (Build -> Select Build Variants)

